# why Macro function,ListView_GetSelectedColumn(),doesn't work? it returns nothing

Tags: c, winapi, desktop-application

I am trying to get the selected column index of the ListView control, but the macro function `ListView_GetSelectedColumn` returns ZERO, no matter how I click.

```cpp
a = ListView_GetSelectedCount(lpNmhdr->hwndFrom);
a = 999;
a = ListView_GetSelectedColumn(lpNmhdr->hwndFrom);
a = SendMessage(lpNmhdr->hwndFrom, LVM_GETSELECTEDCOLUMN, 0, 0);
```

[image: screenshot showing a has value 0 at breakpoint in debugger]

Comment: Does it have a selected column? I don't think you can select a column with the mouse, I think you have to use `LVM_SETSELECTEDCOLUMN` first.

Comment: Are you using Windows Vista+ and ComCtrl v6 in your app? If not, then `LVM_GETSELECTEDCOLUMN` will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue. But I get it working after the following steps. This is my test result:

[image]

> To use ListView_GetSelectedColumn, specify Comctl32.dll version 6 in
>   the manifest. Create a manifest and enable your application to use
>   visual styles.

Refer to [ListView_GetSelectedColumn macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_getselectedcolumn#remarks) and [Enabling Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/cookbook-overview#using-comctl32dll-version-6-in-an-application-that-uses-only-standard-extensions).

Three steps you need to complete:

1. Link to ComCtl32.lib and call InitCommonControls. (You have already done.)
2. Add a file called YourApp.exe.manifest to your source tree that has the XML manifest format. For me as follows:

[image]

3. Add the manifest to your application's resource file as follows:

[image]

Comment: @leibso Glad to help. You can [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) then it will be helpful for other people are searching on this issue.

Comment: just thank you, i walked for years